# Nginx Fastcgi Wordpress 404 Not Found Error For Js and Css Files

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I've nginx, php5-fpm, memcache and wordpress installed on my VPS. I'm getting 404 errors for js and css files.

Errors;

```
[error] 21795#0: *35355 open() "/var/www/example.com/public_html/var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/example/includes/classes/meta-box/js/color.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 88.243.124.30, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/example/includes/classes/meta-box/js/color.js?ver=4.1.1 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit&message=1"
[error] 19044#0: *13800 open() "/var/www/example.com/public_html/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 101.226.33.206, server: www.example.com, request: "GET //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js"
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the first case, you're trying to load a file by its absolute path. Somewhere you have

```
<script src="/var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/example/includes/classes/meta-box/js/color.js?ver=4.1.1"><script>
```

instead of its relative url

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/example/includes/classes/meta-box/js/color.js?ver=4.1.1"><script>
```

In the second case, you're trying to load a file by a relative url

```
<script src="/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js"><script>
```

instead of using an absolute one

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js"><script>
```

I don't know why is this happening, but you should re-check your wp_options table to see what URL you have set.

Comment: Maybe you are right but i tried nothing has changed i think the problem is in the post.php